# Get data from web, convert to variables

Tags: html, arduino, esp32

I have a ESP32 that I use Arduino on to control some relays with a web server.

Right now I am checking the relay state like this:

```
// We now create a URI for the request
String url = "/read.php?id=";

Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
Serial.println(url);

// This will send the request to the server
client.print(String("GET ") + url + "ESP" + ESPid + " HTTP/1.1\r\n"  +
             "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
             "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
unsigned long timeout = millis();

while (client.available() == 0) {
  if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
    Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
    client.stop();
    return;
  }
}


Serial.println(" ");
// Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
while(client.available()){
  line = client.readStringUntil('\r'); //    String
  Serial.println(line); 
}


if (line.toInt() == 100)  
{
  digitalWrite(Rele_1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Rele_2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Rele_3, HIGH);
```

The part with:

```
if (line.toInt() == 100)  
{
  digitalWrite(Rele_1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Rele_2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Rele_3, HIGH);
```

Will be copied and 100 will be changed for every possible variation.

This is not a god way to do it, when I get more relays on it. Each relay will have a 1 or 0 to start and stop.
Is there a way to split the 100 to control the relay? Like if a push `1&0&0` from my web server?
Is there a way to split `1&0&0` or `r1=1&r2=0&r3=0` into variables to control the relays (pins)?

Comment: Maybe I did not understand... but, you want to push a string on your web server and parse it to turn on or off your relays? Like: "1010" would turn on the 4th and second relays... something like this?

Comment: Yes. That is right. Except that 1 is on and 0 is off.

Comment: So, why instead of converting the `line.toInt()` why don't you iterate byte by byte, and then you can simply read the byte value and turn on or off. That would simplify a lot your code. I suppose that `line` is a `String` data type, so you can iterate over each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i choose, was to switch from this:

```
if (line.toInt() == 100)
```

To

```
if (line.charAt(1) == '1')   // Relay 1. 
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the received string, and simply turn on or off the relays as requested (I assume that `line` is a `String`):

```
int sz = line.size();
int relay_pos = sz;
for(i = 0; i < sz; i++,relay_pos--) {
    if(line[i] == 1)
        digitalWrite(relay[relay_pos], HIGH);
    else if(line[i] == 0)
        digitalWrite(relay[relay_pos], LOW);
}
```

Hopefully, this would work in your case.

But, you should have an array of relays, so you can simply pass its index to turn it on or off.

Comment: That is great, except that the last bit is to loop for OTA. Else it is going into delay mode.